# JavaFX TableView with HIbernate

Tags: hibernate, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I am trying to develop a JavaFX Desktop application with Hibernate.
In my data-model I have two entities (Player, Team). Every Player belongs to one Team.

**Player**

id : int
firstName : String
lastName : String
ref_Team : int

**Team**

id : int
Name : String

In my application I have currently two tables for each Entity and everything works well. But now I want to got a step further and in the TableView for Team-Entity I intend to add a column "Players Count".

I know how to bind a TableColumn, e.g. 
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory((data) -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty());

But in my Team-Entity there is no property for counting the Players. 
Any ideas how to bind the numberOfPlayerCol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ObservableList<Player>` with all the players, you can do something like

```
ObservableList<Player> allPlayers = ... ;

TableView<Team> table = new TableView<>();

TableColumn<Team, Number> playerCountCol = new TableColumn<>("Players count");
playerCountCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    Bindings.createLongBinding(() -> 
        allPlayers.stream()
        .filter(player -> player.getTeamId() == cellData.getValue().getId())
        .collect(Collectors.counting()),
        allPlayers));
```

This is a fairly brute force approach which just counts everything whenever it needs. If you run into performance issues, you may need to do something more sophisticated. This should work for modest sizes of data set, though.

Here's a link to a [quick example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/6cd681beea685c500323) (the `Player` here has a direct reference to the `Team`, instead of a field matching its id, but the idea is the same).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you James!